# Qt deployment with external *.lib files

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2010, deployment

I need help with deploying qt application with additional libs (*.lib).
My project developed in VS2010 + Qt5 and use some 3-rd party libs in LIB directory(specified with VS project settings in additional LIBrary directories).
I have searched the right way to deployment and found following solutions:

1. use windeployqt.exe to copy all necessary qt dlls into deploy
   directory.
2. make sure that user have installed redistributable C++
       package for his platform.
3. copy all resources and dependencies
           into structure like in Debug configuration.
4. add paths to the libs
       in app:

QStringList paths = QCoreApplication::libraryPaths();//\n

```
    paths.append(".");
    paths.append("imageformats");
    paths.append("platforms");
    paths.append("sqldrivers");
    paths.append("LIB");   // all *.lib `s there
    QApplication::setLibraryPaths(paths);
```

After this steps my app starts successfully, but when I start using code from external libs, program got crashed! (activate functions from *lib`s)
I`m trying to copy this 3rd party libs in each place that I can imagine - root folder, LIB folder (appended in VS properties), on higher level from app folder - without lucky. Also I have use external dll - it placed next to the app executable file.But it seems that it works.
In debugger I have the next errors:
crash in ntdll.dll

```
CAtlString str = currentFolder->whatsThis().toStdWString().c_str();
//  std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t> >::_Tidy(bool _Built, unsigned __int64 _Newsize)  Line 1998 C++
//  std::allocator<wchar_t>::deallocate(wchar_t * _Ptr, unsigned __int64 __formal)  Line 183    C++
```

What do I need to let my app start working like in debug mode in VS2010? How can I "activate" additional libs in deployed project?

**Update:** Sorry guys, but problem is not in Libs. I have surprised to find that program in VS works **without** libs. I`m using functions only from DLL, no extra dependencies.
All errors come from CRT (ntdll.dll) - like string operation above. It means, as I think, that I have deployed wrong version of MSVCRT100D.dll. I don't know, must it works with debug dll or I need use only MSVCRT100.dll (not debug)?
Also I had changed project version to release and catch following errors on start of program: [image]

In debug configuration it works normally. But in release - vector iterator error in function __tmainCRTStartup()/WinMain().

[image]

what can I do to avoid that problems?

**Update 2:** I forgot rebuild dll to release, but now problem with deallocation ~basic_string() in msvcrt100.dll still actual.
**What difference between run program from VS and run by double click?** (dll builds statically with msvcp100.dll and msvcrt100.dll). Program execution from VS is successful. No string dealloc problems)

Comment: Have you checked your app and dlls with Dependency Walker? You may have missed some runtime dlls.

Comment: *.lib files could be a) static libraries or b) import libraries. In both cases you don't need to deploy them  - it's only build time libraries/dependencies.  As for crash - there could be many reasons, I would create minimal "Hello World" application and check if it crashed when calling your 3rd party libs

Comment: All libs used only from main *dll. Both of errors related to c++ crt/ ntdll. In dependency walker logs: Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found.
Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module in file API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL/IESHIMS.DLL/EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-UICONTEXT-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL and some other system files ...

Comment: Answer this question list: 1). Is 3rd party libs are static or import? 2). Has 3rd party libs been compiled with same VS version? 3). Has 3rd party libs any extra dependencies?

Comment: ***What do I need to let my app start working like in debug mode in VS2010?*** Remember it is against the licence of Visual Studio to deploy a debug build. The Debug CRT is not freely distributable.

Comment: thx, 1) 3rd party libs are static 2) 3rd party libs compiled with same VS version 3) libs has no extra dependencies... And I don`t use libs directly, I use dll, that using 3rd party libs. But program crashed only on libs call points.

Comment: It's not safe to use debug runtime in a release application or release runtime in a debug application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in different Qt and program libraries runtime`s. Destructor in basic_string calls different runtime and program have been crashed.
This is the decision: [crash on std::string destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38076334/qt-c-exception-on-basic-string-destructor-on-double-click-run-only)